# What's the new URL for a Google Images "Quick Search" bookmark in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, google-search

[image]

The above bookmark used to let me search Google Images by typing `goimg mysearchterms` in the address bar, in Firefox.

Now, I get this.

[image]

Obviously, Google has changed something.  But, I can't figure out what.  Additionally, from the current URL format, I can't decipher which bits are necessary to perform a search from the address bar and which are fluff.

The below URLs are for the following search terms, in order:  "google", "myspace", "twitter".

```
http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&q=google&gbv=2&oq=google&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3078l3593l0l4000l6l4l0l0l0l0l203l328l0.1.1l2l0

http://images.google.com/search?q=myspace&tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&gbv=2&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3078l3593l0l4000l6l4l0l0l0l0l203l328l0.1.1l2l0&oq=mys&aq=0&aqi=g10&aql=

http://images.google.com/search?q=twitter&tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&gbv=2&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3078l3593l0l4000l6l4l0l0l0l0l203l328l0.1.1l2l0&oq=twitter&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=
```

What parts of that do I need to add to the Bookmark's "Location", and which bits can be left out?

Comment: They must be rolling out the changes, because  http://images.google.com/images?q=%s still works for me.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Through trial and error, I believe the Location should be:

```
http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%s
```

Comment: I'd tried it with `&q=%s` and `tbm=isch` swapped already, and that produced odd results, but this way does seem to work.  Thanks!

Comment: `.../search?q=%s&tbm=isch` should also work.